# How to convert ISO-2022-KR encoding to UTF-8 encoding using C++?

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8

I am having these characters (Bw@e) which are encoded in charset="iso-2022-kr". The hex values of these characters are 28 0E 42 77 40 65 0F 29.

There is an API available in Unix iconv which can convert the encoding from iso-2022-kr to utf-8.

Example : iconv -f iso-2022-kr -t utf8 Input > Output.

After conversion to UTF-8, Hex values are: 28 EC B0 A8 EC 9E A5 29 (ì°¨ìž¥)

If the above hex values (UTF-8) are decoded using the link below:  https://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder

**Result:**
As raw characters:

(차장)

I am looking for a source code in C++ which can convert the encoding from iso-2022-kr to UTF-8 encoding. I have taken care of the decoding part, which is encoded in UTF-8.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: iconv is also a library (libiconv), and it's one of the best options available.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty C++ program that demonstrates using the iconv library interface (Might require linking with `-liconv`):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iconv.h>

int main() {    
  iconv_t conv = iconv_open("utf-8", "iso-2022-kr");
  if (conv == reinterpret_cast<iconv_t>(-1)) {
    std::perror("iconv_open");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  char iso2022kr_buf[] = "\x28\x0E\x42\x77\x40\x65\x0F\x29";
  char utf8_buf[128];
  std::size_t kr_bytes = sizeof iso2022kr_buf - 1;
  std::size_t utf8_bytes = sizeof utf8_buf;    
  char *as_iso2022kr = iso2022kr_buf;
  char *as_utf8 = utf8_buf;

  std::size_t len = iconv(conv, &as_iso2022kr, &kr_bytes, &as_utf8, &utf8_bytes);
  if (len == static_cast<std::size_t>(-1)) {
    std::perror("iconv");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  *as_utf8 = '\0';
  for (const char *c = utf8_buf; c != as_utf8; c++) {
    std::printf("%02hhX ", *c);
  }
  std::putchar('\n');

  std::puts(utf8_buf);
  
  iconv_close(conv);
  return 0;
}
```

In action:

```
$ g++ -O -Wall -Wextra iconv_demo.cpp
$ ./a.out
28 EC B0 A8 EC 9E A5 29 
(차장)
```